# tsx file error; 'interface' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use interface inside a tsx file but it gives me this error

'interface' declarations can only be used in TypeScript files.

```
import {FC} from 'react'

interface IDepartmentProducts {

}
const AComponent: FC<IDepartmentProducts> = () => {
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found A weird Answer.

for anyone facing the same problem

**just change the extension of the file to .ts and then rename it back to .tsx**

maybe there is a problem with linter or vscode. I don't know :)